# Get CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH from Binary types in Snowflake

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, metadata

I need to get the metadata information on a snowflake table, the DDL is like the following:

```
create or replace TABLE BINARY_TYPES (
    VARCHAR VARCHAR,
    VARCHAR_LEN VARCHAR(1),
    BINARY BINARY,
    BINARY_LEN BINARY(1)
);
```

When I query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns` I have pretty much all the information I need, **except** the BINARY length.

Is there a way to get the size (in this case 8388608 and 1) **without** using `SHOW` statements/`get_ddl`?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get the length without using `SHOW` or `GET_DDL`.

a) Using [DESCRIBE TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/desc-table.html)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE BINARY_TYPES (VARCHAR VARCHAR, VARCHAR_LEN VARCHAR(1),
                                      BINARY BINARY, BINARY_LEN BINARY(1) );

DESCRIBE TABLE BINARY_TYPES;
```

Output:

[image]

---

b) Using  [SYSTEM$TYPEOF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_typeof.html):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE BINARY_TYPES (VARCHAR VARCHAR, VARCHAR_LEN VARCHAR(1), 
                                      BINARY BINARY, BINARY_LEN BINARY(1) );
-- table requires at least single row
INSERT INTO BINARY_TYPES VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

SELECT 
     SYSTEM$TYPEOF(VARCHAR),
     SYSTEM$TYPEOF(VARCHAR_LEN),
     SYSTEM$TYPEOF(BINARY),
     SYSTEM$TYPEOF(BINARY_LEN)
FROM BINARY_TYPES
LIMIT 1;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I don't know at the time the sql is written the column names (in case of b), is there a more generic way to do it? Also the describe doesn't work as I can only run one query with select (I'm using ODBC and describe/show statements aren't handled well)